# Moving File to another folder

Tags: c#

I have this:

```
File.Move(file, trashFolderPath + "\\" + file);
```

where file is some value like:

```
C:\mytest\Images\Hannah, Pow, 199169, 211 Addendum.pdf
```

and second parameter all together has a value like:

```
"C:\\mytest\\ImagesNotFound\\C:\\mytest\\Images\\Hannah, Pow, 199169, 211 Addendum.pdf"
```

But I get this exception:

```
The given path's format is not supported.
```

Comment: That's because the second parameter has C:\\ twice.  Looks like it should be `"C:\\mytest\\Images\\Hannah...."`

Comment: Do you expect this **C:\\mytest\\ImagesNotFound\\C:\\** to be a valid path?

Comment: You should use the `File` class to get the file name without directory extension.

Comment: Ok I got it! It was because I am using Directory.GetFiles and it returns Path name along with the file name...How Can I just get the file names and not the path name?

Comment: Path.GetFileName(file)

Comment: @DionV. No, you don't need to use a string literal if you're using double backslashes. If you were using just single backslashes then you'd need to use a string literal.

Comment: @mason figured it would take the whitespaces as literals. After reading the string again, I saw she had "C://" two times in the path which caused the problem. Commented too fast I guess =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Full file name, that includes the complete path and that is what is being used for `Target` path. Notice the directory letter `C:`. Use:

[Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
File.Move(file, trashFolderPath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(file));
```

You may also use `Path.Combine` instead of concatenating paths like:

```
File.Move(file, Path.Combine(trashFolderPath,Path.GetFileName(file)));
```

Answer (score 2):

"C:\mytest\ImagesNotFound\C:\mytest\Images\Hannah, Pow, 199169, 211 Addendum.pdf" is not a valid file path. So you need to [get the file name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) from `file`, then append that to `trashFolderPath`.

```
File.Move(file, Path.Combine(trashFolderPath, Path.GetFileName(file));
```

Use [`Path.Combine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) to combine path names. It automatically uses the appropriate directory separator, so your code is more portable.